# AVD manager Bug

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing a problem in my VS IDE that the virtual devices doesn't appear and the emulator is offline and when I click on it "it says avd avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK".

I tried to download the AVD manager but it doesn't work .